# Placing markers on map using the latitude and longitude values extracted from MYSQL DB using JSON in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have a set of lat and lon values in MYSQL DB. I retrieved it in android app using JSON (retrieved from PHP code) and I am able to show those locations on map. But I donot know how to place markers on those locations. Please help me.

Following is my code :

```
try {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI website = new URI("http://192.168.1.15/latlonret1.php");
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(website);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String l = "";
    String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(l + nl);
    }
    in.close();
    data = sb.toString();
    // return data;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
    try {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);


        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject json_data1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


            returnString =json_data.getString("lat") + "\n";
            returnString1 =json_data1.getString("lon") + "\n";
            System.out.println(returnString);
            System.out.println(returnString1);
      }
 Intent viewIntent =new Intent(Androidmap.this,Mapview.class);

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("stuff", returnString); 
 bundle.putString("stuff1", returnString1); 
 viewIntent.putExtras(bundle);

 startActivity(viewIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ItemizedOverlays to draw points on a map. Here's a link to Lars Vogel's tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_overlays

Comment: I don't know how to mark points on map using the values retrieved using JSON object.

Comment: Extract the values from your JSON object. Use these values as the GeoPoint in your Itemized Overlay

Answer (score 0):

Use Google map v2. V1 been deprecated and key been no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

After you retreive the location(lat.long) from the JSON that you get from google

Follow these steps

1. Location l=new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
2. Location point_marker=new Location(l);
3. Then you can set the title of the point,vicinity,and other details of the point_marker.bY MAKING A bundle LIKE THIS .
4. Bundle EXTRAS=new Bundle();
5. EXTRAS.putString("TITLE",TITLE);
               EXTRAS.putString("VICINITY", VICINITY);
               poi.setExtras(EXTRAS);
6. So now you have your ArrayList full of location objects which themselves are full of location details.
7. NOW ADD THESE TO THE MAP
8. REtrieve the location objects one by one and for every location create a GEOPOINT and mark it on the map as follows

   for(Location l:locs){
       Log.d("PAIRED-VALUES:",String.valueOf(l.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(l.getLongitude()));
           GeoPoint point =new GeoPoint((int)(l.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(l.getLongitude()*1E6));

   ```
       controller.animateTo(point);
       controller.setZoom(17);
       Map_OverLays=map.getOverlays();



       itemizedoverlay=new HelloItemizedOverlay(draw, context);
       overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,l.getExtras().getString("TITLE"),l.getExtras().getString("VICINITY"));
       itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
       Map_OverLays.add(itemizedoverlay);

       map.invalidate();
   ```

   }

AND HERES THE ITEMIZED OVERLAY CLASS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> Map_Overlays=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    //private ArrayList<OverlayItem> Map_Overlays1=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();        
    Context mcontext;
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable default_marker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(default_marker));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable default_marker,Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(default_marker));
        mcontext=context;       
        //populate();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
@Override
    protected boolean onTap(int arg0) {
    OverlayItem item=Map_Overlays.get(arg0);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;

    }   
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem item)
{
    Log.d("NumberOfTimes" , item.getSnippet());
    Map_Overlays.add(item);
    populate();

}
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Map_Overlays.get(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Map_Overlays.size();
    }

}
```